# How to update the pick list field instead of override using PHP API?

Tags: api, php

I am using the PHP API to update a pick list field.

Say the value in there is XYZ. If I do a POST request as ABC, it only shows ABC.

XYZ gets lost. I need to be able to update a pick list field instead of over ride.

Is this even possible?

Comment: if you don't want to override the value you can fetch the existing value using API and append new value in it.

Comment: Yes, but without an extra API call, maybe Salesforce has some provision using a delimiter perhaps?

Comment: what do you mean by delimiter ?

Comment: if you want to append new value in old one you can write a trigger on your object and on update of record you can update existing value with old value + new value.